# What are the advantages of Oracle UDFs for Teradata?

Tags: oracle, user-defined-functions, teradata

I have been using teradata for a while. Why would Oracle "migrate" into Teradata?
What are the advantages of [Oracle UDFs](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/extensibility/teradata-udfs-for-popular-oracle-functions)

Supposing that you are not creating functions and stored procedures yourself, what is so cool about Oracles UDFs? It appears that almost all functions could be replaced using longer coding lines in Teradata. Is there something that is not supported natively by Teradata (except for regular expressions) that make Oracle UDFs so neccessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those UDFs mainly add some functions which didn't exist in Teradata (before TD14) and because Oracle is the most commonly used DBMS and the most common migration path to Teradata is from Oracle they're called Oracle UDFs.

In fact functions like REPLACE and TRANSLATE are quite basic string functions in other DBMSes, too, and they alleviate the migration. And you definitely don't want to rewrite an oREPLACE or oTRANSLATE in plain old Standard SQL using SUBTRINGS and POSITIONS :-)

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-7228/fsoverview-12/index.html):-

> - Ability to access the industry standard CD-ROM and DVD-ROM media when    they contain a UDF file system.
> - Flexibility in exchanging information across platforms and operating    systems.
> - A mechanism for implementing new applications rich in    broadcast-quality video, high-quality sound along with the richness
>     in interactivity using the DVD video specification based on UDF
>     format.

Also [Functions Not Supported by Teradata](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/gateways.102/b14280/apb.htm)

> Oracle SQL functions with no equivalent function in Teradata are not
>   supported in DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statements, but are evaluated
>   by the Oracle database server if the statement is a SELECT statement.
>   That is, the Oracle database server performs post-processing of SELECT
>   statements sent to the gateway.
>
> If an unsupported function is used in a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE,
>   statement, the following Oracle error occurs:
>
> ```
> ORA-02070: database db_link_name does not support function in this context
> ```